# In what format is the timestamp 413033364.14671?

Tags: ios, timestamp

I have to analyze a database coming from an iOS app, containing timestamps of the form

```
413033364.146713
```

or

```
413030924.054397
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like any format I know. Does anyone recognize it ?

Comment: Is the database a SQLite file for Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can only guess because we don't know how the timestamp was created.
But

```
NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:413033364.146713];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

produces `2014-02-02 11:29:24 +0000`, which is *today*.

If that is what you expect, then your timestamp is the number of
seconds since 1 January 2001, GMT.

Answer (score 4):

If you are more curious about the reason for that: NSDate's reference is a "time value relative to an absolute reference date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT."

Source: Apple's NSDate Class Reference